# Get a value inside a list generated by psutil.sensors_temperatures()

Tags: python, list

I want to get a value inside a list generated by `psutil.sensors_temperatures()`. How do I get 50.0 value inside this list?

```
list = [shwtemp(label='', current=50.0, high=103.0, critical=103.0)]
```

Comment: Use the `.append()` function of python lists

Answer (score 4):

Tried this on my raspberry pi, this will help you understand:

**1) run the code**

```
import psutil

# get the output from psutil
cpu_temp = psutil.sensors_temperatures()
print(cpu_temp)
print(type(cpu_temp))
```

**output:**
<class 'dict'>
{'cpu_thermal': [shwtemp(label='', current=39.433, high=None, critical=None)]}

turns out that the output is a dictionary

**2) get the element of the dict that you want**

```
# get the first element of the dictionary
cpu_temp = psutil.sensors_temperatures()["cpu_thermal"]
print(cpu_temp)
print(type(cpu_temp))
```

**output:**
<class 'list'>
[shwtemp(label='', current=39.433, high=None, critical=None)]

turns out that the output is a list, notice that the list has only one element (the shwtemp(...) class)

**3) get the first (and only) element of the list**

```
# get this first element 
cpu_temp = psutil.sensors_temperatures()["cpu_thermal"][0]
print(cpu_temp)
print(type(cpu_temp))
```

**output:**
<class 'psutil._common.shwtemp'>
shwtemp(label='', current=39.433, high=None, critical=None)

now we finally have the inner element that we were looking for, namely the psutil.common.shwtemp class

**4) get the current temperature**

```
# get the temperature
cpu_temp = psutil.sensors_temperatures()["cpu_thermal"][0]
print(cpu_temp.current)
```

**output:**
39.433

Answer (score 0):

I tried too pull temperature value generated by `psutil. acptiz` is a list inside the dictionary.

```
temp=(psutil.sensors_temperatures().get('acpitz')[0][1])
```